# ASP.NET Core MVC with Identity 2 & EntityFramework 6(Oracle)

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-6, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity-2

I am using `ASP.NET Core MVC` with **`EntityFramework 6`**(not EF Core, because oracle not provide EF7 for Oracle support yet)

i am unable to use AddEntityFrameworkStores since ApplicationDbContext required to be `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`

I dont have to use EntityFramework In Identity, Is it other way i use **Asp.NET Core Identity with Oracle**.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {    

var a=services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CoreCompat.IdentityRole>();
            a.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();//Error Compile

        }
```

Error   CS0311  The type 'x.Models.ApplicationDbContext' cannot be used as type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method 'IdentityEntityFrameworkBuilderExtensions.AddEntityFrameworkStores(IdentityBuilder)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'x.Models.ApplicationDbContext' to 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'. MPWebApplicationCore..NET Framework 4.5.2

Answer (score 0):

i Found an example for ASP.NET Core Identity without Entity Framework

for asp.net core
change dependencies from `Microsoft.AspNet` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore`
change `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`

https://github.com/MatthewKing/IdentityWithoutEF/tree/58631cda6e1a719ea513e49ba65c152d8cf78ec1